# Airflow SLA miss implementation

Tags: airflow

i am new to Airflow and trying to implement the sla miss functionality in my DAG

```
default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2017,07,24),
    'email': ['jspsai@gmail.com'],
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 5,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'sla':timedelta(seconds=30),
    'pool':'demo',
    'queue':'slaq',
    'run_as_user':'ec2-user'
}
```

but this sla is not applied and i am not able to figure out what the issue is

I also gave the sla at the task level as well with no luck.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

I don't know if this will fix your problem but one thing about sla's in Airflow is that they only work with a scheduled task. If you run them manually sla's are not being considered.

Comment: Can you please share the source of this information? I could not find something like this in documentation, and my implementation did not worked.

Comment: do not know if it is still the case now but back then i spent an whole afternoon testing this. just trial and check.

Comment: At least your comment resolved the partial problem I was facing.